# The argumet type ' ' can't be assign to the parameter tyepe List <>

Tags: dart

I am trying to get a list of students from the function `seasonalStudents` and use it in another function `studentListener`

I want to use `unHapyyStd` but in this line `unHappyStd = [StaticStudents(std.id, null, TotalStudents(std.id, null))];` I get an error `The argument type TotalStudents can't be assigned to the parameter Type List<TotalStudents>` , How do I fix it ?

```
class Toppers {
  String id;
  double passmark;
  double failmark;

  Toppers(this.id, this.passmark, this.failmark);
}

class TotalStudents {
  final String id;
  final Image markerIcon;

  TotalStudents(
    this.id,
    this.markerIcon,
  );
}

class StaticStudents {
  final String id;
  final String call;
  final List<TotalStudents> totalStds;

  StaticStudents(this.id, this.call, this.totalStds);
}

class Students {}

class NearPassedStudents {
  String id;
  double passmark;
  double failmark;

  NearPassedStudents(this.id, this.passmark, this.failmark);
}

class GeoStudents {
  static List<NearPassedStudents> passedStudentsList = [];
}

void seasonalStudents() {
  for (NearPassedStudents std in GeoStudents.passedStudentsList) {
    print("student: ${std.id}");
    print("student: ${std.passmark}");
    print("student: ${std.failmark}");

    unHappyStd = [StaticStudents(std.id, null, TotalStudents(std.id, std.passmark))];
  }

  Future<void> studentListener()async{
    ////some method
    /// use it here
    case studentX:
       seasonalStudents();
  }
}
```

Comment: That is because 3rd parameter is expecting List<Obj> and you are only passing object. Pass List<Obj> instead

Comment: Yes I understand that , Can you provide an example of the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the third argument in the `StaticStudents` constructor expects the type `List<TotalStudents>` but you are sending a `TotalStudents` object as argument:

```
StaticStudents(std.id, null, TotalStudents(std.id, null))
```

Instead, make it a `List` with the following if you just want a list with a single `TotalStudents` to be used:

```
StaticStudents(std.id, null, [TotalStudents(std.id, null)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As your 3rd argument require list instead of just obj. inside your loop you can do like this

```
var list = <TotalStudents>[];
list.add(TotalStudents(std.id, null));

unHappyStd = [StaticStudents(std.id, null, list)];
```

Comment: You are allowed to create a list containing elements when creating the list. So `var list = [TotalStudents(std.id, null)];` is allowed. Dart can also here automatically determine the type of the `List` since it can see what element we are initializing the `List` with.

Comment: yes you are right. @pannam you can also do as per suggestion